# In Bootstrap, Left and right align items using push, pull or bootstrap columns. which is better?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hy Guys,

Using Bootstrap, you could use pull or push classes for left and right aligned items on a single row but you could also use default column sizes for left and right aligned classes. A typical example would be a logo on the left and top navigation on the right.

I would like to know which is the better way to left align and right align items. For example if to put a logo on the left and main navigation on the right.

Regards,
dkj

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should use `col-*-*` in conjunction with `col-*-offset-*`. For example, you could make a `col-md-4` "push" to the right without floating by putting `col-md-offset-8` on it.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap have classes `col-sm-*` which slice your screen into grids.
Bootstrap takes 12 grids on a page means your page is divided into 12 columns so its upto you how many grid you want to assign to a particular `div`
For your example:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        Here comes the logo image
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
        Here comes the navigation code
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, logo will come on the left side with 5/12 part of screen and navigation will come on the right with 7/12 part of the screen.
`col-sm-*` here `sm` defines the screen size. Other variations are `col-xs-*, col-md-*, col-lg-*`